# Check if environment variable is set in configure script?

Tags: environment-variables, autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to test if `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` is set in an Autoconf script. The relevant stanza is shown below. According to [How can I check an environment variable?](http://gnu-autoconf.7623.n7.nabble.com/How-can-I-check-an-environment-variable-td13092.html) on the Autoconf mailing list, I can use:

```
if test "${var+set}" = set; then
  echo "variable \$var is set to: $var"
fi
```

The variable is not set, but my `AC_MSG_ERROR` is not being executed.

```
$ printenv | grep ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
$
```

Instead, the test is producing the following error:

```
./configure: line 20616: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./configure: line 20616: `  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6'
```

(There's another reply in the thread but it seems to be just a comment and does not answer the question).

How do I test if an environmental variable is set in Autoconf?

---

Here is the stanza I am trying to execute in `configure.ac`:

```
# if test "$IS_ANDROID_OS" != "0"; then
if true; then

   if test "${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT+set}" != set; then
     AC_MSG_ERROR([ANDROID_NDK_ROOT is not set. Please set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT])
   fi 

   THIS_FILE="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.h"
   AC_CHECK_FILE([$THIS_FILE],
      [cp "$THIS_FILE" "$ac_srcdir"],
      AC_MSG_RESULT([cpu-features.h does not exist in ANDROID_NDK_ROOT, skipping])
   )

   THIS_FILE="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c"
   AC_CHECK_FILE([$THIS_FILE],
      [cp "$THIS_FILE" "$ac_srcdir"],
      AC_MSG_RESULT([cpu-features.c does not exist in ANDROID_NDK_ROOT, skipping])
   )
fi
```

---

Here is the chunk of `configure` from `cat -n`:

```
 20610
 20611     THIS_FILE="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c"
 20612     as_ac_File=`$as_echo "ac_cv_file_$THIS_FILE" | $as_tr_sh`
 20613  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for $THIS_FILE" >&5
 20614  $as_echo_n "checking for $THIS_FILE... " >&6; }
 20615  if eval \${$as_ac_File+:} false; then :
 20616    $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
 20617  else
 20618    test "$cross_compiling" = yes &&
 20619    as_fn_error $? "cannot check for file existence when cross compiling""$LINENO" 5
 20620  if test -r "$THIS_FILE"; then
 20621    eval "$as_ac_File=yes"
 20622  else
 20623    eval "$as_ac_File=no"
 20624  fi
```

Comment: I don't think the error you observe is related to the shell syntax you're using for testing whether `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` is set.  The error message itself leads me to suspect mismatched quotes, but I don't see that in the script excerpt.  I can, however, reproduce the issue using very little more than the posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your shell syntax for testing whether a variable is set, and it works fine with Autoconf.

The problem appears to arise from failing to quote the third arguments to the `AC_CHECK_FILE()` macros.  You should always quote (with square brackets) each argument to each macro, *especially* when that argument is or contains a macro call itself.  I can reproduce a syntax error in `configure` by wrapping the example code you provided between an `AC_INIT` and an `AC_OUTPUT`, but it goes away with proper quoting. Specifically, here:

```
   THIS_FILE="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.h"
   AC_CHECK_FILE([$THIS_FILE],
      [cp "$THIS_FILE" "$ac_srcdir"],
      [AC_MSG_RESULT([cpu-features.h does not exist in ANDROID_NDK_ROOT, skipping])]
   )

   THIS_FILE="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c"
   AC_CHECK_FILE([$THIS_FILE],
      [cp "$THIS_FILE" "$ac_srcdir"],
      [AC_MSG_RESULT([cpu-features.c does not exist in ANDROID_NDK_ROOT, skipping])]
   )
```

Failing to quote the argument results in it being expanded too many times, and the resulting output indeed is not syntactically valid shell code.

Comment: Thanks John. My test machine is bogged down with building Clang. I need to wait a couple of hours to free up some test time. I'm also out of upvotes so I need to wait until tonight to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this old question and figured I'd share a solution I ended up using when I needed to check multiple variables were set (in this sanitized example, `VAR1` thru `VAR4`):

```
m4_foreach_w([my_var],[VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4],[
  AS_VAR_IF(myvar, [], AC_MSG_ERROR([Missing required variable: myvar!]))
  AC_SUBST(myvar)dnl Export variable to Makefile as well
  AC_ARG_VAR(myvar, [])dnl if this variable changes, re-run configuration
])
```